# Tell an existing thread to do something Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, eventmachine

I'm playing a bit with event machine, and got some code that run on another thread, I want his callback to get synced back to the main thread, so I'd like to do something like this:

```
thread.post { fiber.resume(result) }
```

The fiber parent is thread but context of execution is on another thread.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found it

> EventMachine.schedule

does the trick